# How to split a PDF by titles with a specific size or font

Tags: c#, pdf, split, itext

I'm trying to split a PDF by his titles depending of his size or font.

Currently I could only extract the fonts of a PDF but I need to know the size or font to see if that text is a title. I don't know how to read the PDF by his titles with an specific size or font, I know it can extract the text but is just that, simple text, how do you know which size or font has that text ?

By the way, I have been able to split the PDF by his bookmarks and also the bookmark's "kids"

but I need to split the PDF more deeper. Is that why I'm trying to get the titles to split the PDF by them.

I made some research but I couldn't get something very useful for this case.

Here some questions:

- How do you get the size?
- How do you get the font?
- How do you iterate the PDF line by line?
- How do you check a text(line) if has a specific font?

Some code

```
HashSet<String> fontNames = new HashSet<string>();
PdfDictionary resources;
for (int p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
{
    PdfDictionary dic = reader.GetPageN(p);
    resources = dic.GetAsDict(PdfName.RESOURCES);

    if (resources != null)
    {
        //get fonts dictionary
        PdfDictionary fonts = resources.GetAsDict(PdfName.FONT);
        if (fonts != null)
        {
            PdfDictionary font;
            foreach (PdfName key in fonts.Keys)
            {
                font = fonts.GetAsDict(key);
                String name = font.GetAsName(PdfName.BASEFONT).ToString();
                fontNames.Add(name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Another way
`List<object[]> fonts2 = BaseFont.GetDocumentFonts(reader);`

Other code: get text

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);

words = currentText.Split('\n');
for (int j = 0, len = words.Length; j < len; j++)
{
    line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]));
}
```

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(words[j]))` - What does this achieve?

Comment: That being asked, to be able to analyze extracted text by its style, you need to extend the existing text extraction strategy or create a new one from sketch. Here you either change the result and integrate style information in it or you do the processing by style already in the strategy. There are examples on stack overflow for either kind. Which approach is better, depends on the very use case at hand.

Comment: Hello @mkl, thank you for your answer, It really helped me to know what I should investigate.Yesterday I was trying some things and I could get what I needed it.
I used this
```public void RenderText(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo renderInfo)```
and the renderInfo parameter has all what I need

```
renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName;
renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
```

Comment: Great! You may want to put that into an actual answer (not a mere comment) which you then can mark as *accepted answer* to help others looking for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

`public void RenderText(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo renderInfo)`

and the ***renderInfo*** parameter has all what I needed it.

```
renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName;  // Font Name
renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint(); // Coordinates - (56.6929 , 727.8466, 1)
renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint(); // Coordinates - (96.78018, 737.1749, 1)
```